# HERE iOS SDK premium - Is there a way to prevent "waypoints" / Stopovers from being announced?

Tags: here-api

I am making an iOS Premium application, the routes that are loaded for the user have lots of waypoints, each turn is added as a waypoint to ensure the specific route is followed exactly as it was saved.
This mucks up the voice guidance, rather than announcing the next turn the guidance announces "After ... you will reach your stopover"
I would prefer it to say "After ... turn left" like normal, as if there were no waypoints. Is this possible? Where can I configure the voice guidance?

Answer (score 2):

You have few options.

**FIRST:**

Enables/disables voice prompts for certain maneuver.

```
@interface NMANavigationManager : NSObject
.....
- (BOOL)setVoiceEnabled:(BOOL)enabled forManeuverAction:(NMAManeuverAction)action
.....



NMAManeuver.h
/**

* Defines types of actions for a NMAManeuver.

*/

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NMAManeuverAction) {

    /** An undefined action. */

    NMAManeuverActionUndefined = 0,             // 0

    /** An indication there is no action associated with the maneuver. */

    NMAManeuverActionNone,                      // 1

    /** An action that indicates the end of a route. */

    NMAManeuverActionEnd,                       // 2

    /** An action that indicates a stopover. */

    NMAManeuverActionStopover,                  // 3

    /** An action that indicates a junction. */

    NMAManeuverActionJunction,                  // 4

    /** An action that indicates a roundabout. */

    NMAManeuverActionRoundabout,                // 5

    /** An action that indicates a u-turn. */

    NMAManeuverActionUTurn,                     // 6

    /** An action that indicates entering a highway from the right. */

    NMAManeuverActionEnterHighwayFromRight,     // 7

    /** An action that indicates entering a highway from the left. */

    NMAManeuverActionEnterHighwayFromLeft,      // 8

    /** An action that indicates entering a highway. */

    NMAManeuverActionEnterHighway,              // 9

    /** An action that indicates leaving a highway. */

    NMAManeuverActionLeaveHighway,              // 10

    /** An action that indicates changing from one highway to another. */

    NMAManeuverActionChangeHighway,             // 11

    /** An action that indicates continuing along a highway. */

    NMAManeuverActionContinueHighway,           // 12

    /** An action that indicates boarding a ferry. */

    NMAManeuverActionFerry,                     // 13

    /** An action that indicates passing a junction. */

    NMAManeuverActionPassJunction,              // 14

    /** An action that indicates heading after leaving public transit station. */

    NMAManeuverActionHeadTo,                    // 15

    /** An action that indicates passing a station. */

    NMAManeuverActionPassStation,               // 16

    /** An action that indicates transit line change. */

    NMAManeuverActionChangeLine,                // 17



    /** An invalid action. */

    NMAManeuverActionInvalid = -1

};
```

**SECOND:**
You may use delegate method. Just return NO and you won't hear any voice feedback.

```
@protocol NMANavigationManagerDelegate<NSObject>
@optional
......
-(BOOL)navigationManager:(NMANavigationManager *)navigationManager shouldPlayVoiceFeedbackWithText:(NSString *)text
.....
```

But in that case you would have to parse "feedback text" to understand whether you went to play a feedback.

Comment: I added this:         NMANavigationManager.sharedInstance().setVoiceEnabled(false, forManeuverAction: NMAManeuverAction.stopover)
Now I receive no voice guidance.

Comment: We are able to get the voice guidance. Can provide geo-coordinates for stopovers you are trying to suppress? and also provide the code snippet as well

Comment: Every "waypoint" in this saved route XML is added as a waypoint to the navigable route. This is the saved route Key (URL encoded) AIQACAAAAB4AAABdAAAAmQAAAKYAAAB42mNYxsDOxAAEYKJDc8Ij41xtdQYoWLKjSCiJqdKa4f9%2FiMCH%2FQxIgAuIZ%20cuAxrAkrH3Ua%20xIFzjeotCoSaGSis8GtnWJN5lhNoLBro%2FZmxbB6Q5GBqAOBAoxdRgAFRxgoHBYQIDABtSHcgKNqdh

Comment: private func startGuidance(route: NMARoute) {
        mapView.add(mapObject: NMAMapRoute(route)!)
        NMANavigationManager.sharedInstance().map = mapView

        NMANavigationManager.sharedInstance().setVoiceEnabled(false, forManeuverAction: NMAManeuverAction.stopover)
        // Comment this out to start real guidance.
        enableGuidanceSimulation(route: route)
        NMANavigationManager.sharedInstance().startTurnByTurnNavigation(route)
    }

Comment: Here is a video demonstrating the stopover voice being on or off: http://youtu.be/CXcHgAtohJA?hd=1

Comment: If stopover point is placed right on a junction or very close before it voice prompt for the maneuver on the junction won't play. It does not depend on whether the voice prompt for stopover is enabled. As workaround you can use the VIA waypoint type.

Comment: If I change the waypoints to a "viaWaypoint" then my test route doesn't calculate. This is the line I changed                             waypointArray.append(NMAWaypoint(geoCoordinates: waypointGeocordArray.last!, waypointType: NMAWaypointType.viaWaypoint))

Comment: Is there a flaw in my methodology?  I need a route to exactly recreate as it was saved, e.g. it is a "single trip permit" route for overdimensional travel and any deviation from the route is illegal. To recreate the route exactly I am saving each turn in the original route and entering each turn as a waypoint in the re-created route. If there is a better way to save and re-create a route so that I get turn by turn navigation then please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I added the parameter "&representation=navigation" to the getRoute call. I then each position (in the shape) to add each waypoint as an "NMAWaypointType.viaWaypoint" except for the first and last waypoint which are NMAWaypointType.stopWaypoint. Once doing this the correct route was represented and correct voice guidance played during the route.