# startTurnByTurnNavigation maximum viaWaypoints

Tags: swift, here-api

I am creating a route with many viaWaypoints to ensure that a route is correctly re-created( as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/57302391/4344420 ). When there are too many waypoints the route fails. Is there a maximum number of viaWaypoints and what is it?
The error code for error.rawValue from the code below is "1"

```
        coreRouter.calculateRoute(withStops: waypoints, routingMode: NMARoutingMode()) { routeResult, error in
        if error != NMARoutingError.none {
            print("Error: Routing failed. Maybe you are overseas?")
            self.labelTest.text = "Error: Routing failed."
            NSLog(String(error.rawValue))
            return
        }
```

Comment: Please provide the error you receive on route calculation.

Comment: I get value "1" from error.rawValue from the code below: coreRouter.calculateRoute(withStops: waypoints, routingMode: NMARoutingMode()) { routeResult, error in
            if error != NMARoutingError.none {
                print("Error: Routing failed. Maybe you are overseas?")
                self.labelTest.text = "Error: Routing failed."
                NSLog(String(error.rawValue))

Answer (score 1):

While there is no maximum limit imposed on how many waypoints is allowed for a route, increasing the number of waypoints increases the probability that the route request will fail and a safe upper limit of 128 is recommended.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMACoreRouter.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMACoreRouter(im)calculateRouteWithStops:routingMode:completionBlock: